# How to check shopping cart empty magento 2?

Tags: checkout, cart

I calling a button proceed to checkout on title page shopping cart.
[image]
[image]
but when cart empty, button still show.
[image]
how to check if cart empty and hide button proceed to checkout?
Please help me!

Comment: Could you please share topmetod.phtml and toplink.phtml file code in text format in OP

Answer (score 2):

You can use the cart helper to check if shopping cart is empty.

```
protected $cartHelper;

public function __construct(     
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper
    ) {
        $this->cartHelper = $cartHelper;
    }
```

and then you can add your logic if the cart is empty

```
   if ($this->cartHelper->getItemsCount() === 0) {
          //add your logic 
   }
```

Comment: I see protected $_cartHelper; in vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart.php
but I try running if ($this->_cartHelper->getItemsCount() === 0){...} body show only div page-title-wrapper and nothing else. :(

Comment: Here $cartHelper is a variable defined for the helper class. you need to check for getItemsCount() function in vendor/magento/module-checkout/Helper/Cart.php

$this->cartHelper->getItemsCount() // This will returns your cart count

Comment: oh. thankyou!. I'm trying other code:  if ($block->getItemsCount() != 0) {
.................my code.....
 } and It worked well.